# Треугольник, но угла трИ?

Tags: словообразование

Как образовалось слово "треугольник"? Что такое "е"? Соединительная? В украинском, например, "три" и "трикутник" буква та же. (только "и" читается как "ы": "тры" и "трыкутнык"). Спасибо!

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Но почему Вы не в "ответах" пишите?

Comment: Берегу нервы)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Числительное *три* в слове *тре(х)угольник* стоит в косвенном падеже, ср. :
трехугольник ("о трех углах")
четырехугольник ("о четырех углах")
пятиугольник ("о пяти углах")
и тд.
Три, трех, трем, трех/три, тремя, о трех.
Можно порассуждать, какой падеж применен, Р. или П., хотя это не очень важно. Фигура из трех углов или "о трех углах".
Одноклассник, двухвостка, трезубец, четырехскатка, пятиходовка, шестилетка, семицветик, восьмипудовый, девятиголовый, тридцатиярусный, сорокалапый - числительное входит в состав слова не в своей начальной форме. Исключение : **сто**ведерный и тп.

Дополнение (о форме **дву**).
Числительное *два* изменялось в древнерусском и ЦС языках только в двойственном числе. Форма родительного и предложного падежей указана в двух вариантах :
**двою** или **дву** (для всех родов).
Обе эти формы и входят в состав сложных слов : *двоегласие*, *двоеженец*, *одвуконь*, *двугривенный*. Каким образом Ю превратилось в Е - тема для научной статьи. В русском языке есть только одно слово с начальным *двоЮ* : **двоюродный**. Слово произносится легко, с ударением на Ю, поэтому до сих пор сохранилось такое написание. Из словаря Фасмера :

> ДВОЮРОДНЫЙ 
>  (брат). Образовано из **род.-местн. дв.** др.-русск., ст.-слав. **дъвою** родоу, см. два и род (Френкель, ZfslPh 13,207).

Встречается также форма **дво**, без переходно-соединительной гласной : *двословие, двосрочие, двоточие*. 
Общий принцип постановки числительного в форму Р.п. в сложных словах подтверждается более поздним развитием русской формы **двух** (то есть слово *два* в Р. и П. падежах мн.ч.). Ранее ее не было : *А мостьнику ехати самому съ отрокомъ на дву коню* (1282). **Двухгривеночная пищаль** -  из источника 1643 г.  В 18 веке все еще продолжали употреблять падежную форму *на дву* :

> Документы следственных дел Ваньки Каина и других московских преступников (1741-1752) И в то время никого не дождались, и пошли было К Москве, и проехав Ростокино, ехали к ним навстречу из Москвы **в одних санях на дву лошедях**, которой сказывался Троицы-Сергиевой лавры служителем, и при нем был один подводчик.

*На дву лошедях* - **дву** является реликтом дв. числа, а существительное **лошедях** стоит уже во мн. числе.

Comment: С первой частью "тре" пишутся также слова "тренога, стреножить", видимо, по этой же причине

Comment: А  стреножить  -  это  связать  две передних ноги  лошади.  Может  в  этом  слове  ТРЕ  не  от  ТРИ ?

Comment: Хотя  при  этом  лошадь  становится  как  бы  трёхногой.  Тогда,  конечно,  в  корне  -  числительное.

Comment: >В русском языке есть только одно слово с начальным двоЮ   
  
Все слова с "двой-" не от "двою"? Двойка, двойной.

Answer (score 5):

У меня нет однозначного ответа. 
Не стал бы отвечать, кабы не предыдущий ответ.

В двух словах. Я крепко сомневаюсь, что это именно падежная форма какого-то падежа. С таким же успехом можно свести к соединительной гласной. Похоже, что-то в языке ныне утерянное и сохранившееся только в подобных образованиях. Надо, видимо, проделать большую работу и поднимать грамматику старославянского, чтобы прийти к каким-то выводам о правилах и грамматике употребления этих форм.

Вот что по этому поводу у Валгиной:

*Примечание 4. Числительные два, три в составе сложных слов имеют формы двух-, трех- и дву-, три-, тре-: двухдневный, трехчасовой; двуногий, двупалый, двуспальный; тридесятый, тримаран ('яхта с тремя килями'), трилистник; трезубец, треглавый и трехглавый, тренога, треножить, треугольник, треух.*

[1.8.2. Сложные слова без соединительной гласной](http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook142/01/part-009.htm#1.8.2.)

Почему-то не оговорена форма "трое": троекратный. А еще двоякий и троякий. Вариантов масса.

Там и про остальные числительные много примечаний, каждое образуется по каким-то своим внутренним законам. Во всяком случае валить в одну кучу "одно-" и "тре" объявляя все косвенным падежом (каким именно, кстати?) как-то не смотрится.

Сравните еще "обоеполый" - уж форма-то "обое" от "оба/обе" точно ни в каком падеже не замечена.

Comment: >"трое"
**Двое***женец. 

>обоеполый
Двуполый. 




Comment: Что "двоеженец" и "двуполый"?
Что случай сложный, я понимаю.  
А есть примеры призваны что-то опровегнуть, то я не очень понимаю, что именно.  

Кстати, разговарить с Дерзким серьезно я зарекся, но тут смею напомнить, что обе формы - древнеславянские - и по каким словарям он их сравнивал - сам дьявол не разберется.

Answer (score 5):

При образовании сложных слов на основе числительных  в большинстве случаев используется  сложение ЧИСЛИТЕЛЬНОГО В ФОРМЕ Р.П. с основой опорного существительного или прилагательного (исключение: числительные  сто, девяносто используются в форме И.п.)
Способ образования прилагательных: суффиксальное сложение.
Два года → двух-лет-н-ий и дву-лет-н-ий  (усеченная форма).
Три палубы  → трех- палуб-н-ый, три угла → тре-уголь- н –ый (усеченная форма)→ треугольн-ик.

ИНФОРМАЦИЯ ПО ПОВОДУ УСЕЧЕННЫХ ФОРМ  (кстати, интересный и неоднозначный вопрос для обсуждения):

Форма ДВУ является формой существовавшего когда-то двойственного числа. Можно сказать, что число два в этом случае имеет обобщенное значение и задает определенное качество сложному слову (становится возможной  замена синонимом): двужильный человек (сильный), двуличный человек (лицемерный.
Сложные слова с числительным три образуются с помощью основной количественной формы Р.п.  ТРЁХ  и дополнительных форм с обобщённым значением ТРЕ и ТРИ. Эти исключительные формы рекомендуется запомнить:треугольник, трезубец, трезвучие тренога; трилогия, тридесятый тридевятый, трилистник.

Так каков же Ваш вариант образования слова треугольник: роль буквы Е,  способ образования? Если форму ТРЕ нельзя назвать усеченной формой ТРЕХ, то что это за форма?

ИНФОРМАЦИЯ ИЗ ИНТЕРНЕТА

Из истории слов
Число «3» входит в сложные слова в разных формах. Во-первых, существует ряд слов, образованных сложением с основой тре- (от не сохранившегося наречия тре – «трижды»): треугольник, трезубец, треножник, треух, трезвон, треволнение.

Во-вторых, сращением со словом три образованы числительные тринадцать, тридцать, триста, а также некоторые другие слова: Тригорское (от «три горы»), тридесятое (царство), втридорога.

Обе эти модели непродуктивны. Зато продуктивна модель с основой трех – формой родительного падежа числительного три (трехдневный, трехсложный, трехведерный).

Сложные слова с количественным числительным два также образуются от разных основ: дву- и двух-: двуглавый и двухголовый, двуличный и двухместный. Основа дву- – это тоже форма родительного падежа, но только для парных предметов (т.е. предметов, нормально существующих в паре).

Comment: Трилистник/trifolium (лат.) - русский **трехлистник**.  
Трилогия/τριλογία (греч.), тримаран, трицепс, триатлон, триколор, триплекс, триумвират, триклиний, но трельяж -  иностранные заимствования.  
Триглав - не трехголовый.  
Форма **тре** может означать *много* : треклятый, трезвон, треволнения.

Comment: >Форма ДВУ является формой существовавшего когда-то двойственного числа.  
  
Ну если уж совсем точно говорить, то по грамматическим свойствам числительное "два" (и оба) рассматривалось как существительное двойственного числа (других чисел не имело). "Дву" наряду с "двою" было одной из форм родительного и предложного падежа (для всех трех родов). Но оно и сейчас так - с небольшими фонетическим изменениями.    
К сожалению, этот ыакт никак не придлижает нас к ответу на вопрос о том, что таое "тре" и вообще о выборе формы числительного в составе слов.

Comment: София, если вдуматься, то не форма ТРЕ усеченная, а форма ТРЕХ - дополненная.Сравните : *Треязычный Лексикон Поликарпова* и современное слово *трехъязычный*.

Comment: В  устной  речи  трёхугольник  звучит  также  естественно  как  и  четырёхугольник.  
У  Даля  -  четыреклассное  училище,  а  в  скобках  -  четырёхклассное  училище,  как  более  поздний  вариант.  У  него  же  как  равноправное:  четвероугольный.  Сейчас  так  не  говорят.  Значит  форма  с  добавленным  "х"  более  продуктивна.

Comment: >Форма тре может означать много : треклятый, трезвон, треволнения.  
  
И что она означет? Хотя бы одно что-нибудь.

>София, если вдуматься, то не форма ТРЕ усеченная, а форма ТРЕХ - дополненная.   

Смотря что считать исходным. 
Но вроде бы эти формы параллельны.

Comment: Треклятый  -  возможно  трижды  проклятый,  трезвон - возможно  разновидность  колокольного  звона,  а  с  треволнениями  как-то  трудно...

Comment: В общем виде префикс *тре-* означает "высшую степень качества".  
Формы ТРЕ  и ДВУ - более ранние, чем удлиненные их варианты. Прослеживается по всем известным словарям.

Comment: Двоеженец - корень (первый) двой. Тот же, что и в "двою-". 
А все вместе: нет каких-то ясных правил для разделения случаев с "двое"/"дву"/"двух" и "трое"/"тре"/"трех".

Comment: >от не сохранившегося наречия тре – «трижды» 
  
Интересно, от какой основы образовано сие "наречие"? Хабургаев о подобных образованиях не говорит ничего. 
Зато явно говорит, что "Тр(i)ех" и "тр(i)е" - разные падежные формы числительного три.  
Спорить о том, какая из них древнее или исходнее - это переписывать история про курицу и яйцо.
Вообще разговоры про усеченные (или наращенные) формы отдают какой-то фантасмагорией.