# Трезубец. Написание слова. Очень важно и срочно!

Tags: орфография

Почему трезубец пишем с буквой Е? Срочно! Пожалуйста ответьте: почему «три», но трезубец?

Кто первый ответит, тому + и репутация!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Сложные слова с числительным ТРИ** образуются с помощью основной количественной формы Р.п.  ТРЁХ  и дополнительных форм  ТРЕ и ТРИ (эти исключительные формы рекомендуется запомнить):

***трёхместный, трёхпалубный трёхтомный***  – основная форма ТРЁХ,

***треугольник, трезубец, трезвучие, тренога*** – исключительная форма ТРЕ,

***трилогия, тридесятый,  тридевятый, трилистник***  –  исключительная форма ТРИ.

Исключительные формы связаны с происхождением слова, в частности их написание может объясняться побуквенным заимствованием (транслитерацией). Поэтому вряд ли можно назвать корректным такое высказывание: *Трезубец — жезл с тремя зубцами. С тремя, а не тримя*.

К примеру, слово ***трилогия*** заимствовано из французского языка в XIX веке,  восходит к греческому слову trilogia, поэтому используется форма ТРИ. Но в слове трезубец (с русским корнем) форма изменена. Почему? История этого  слова не так однозначна, чтобы быстро найти правильный ответ.

Похожий вопрос обсуждался на форуме, мнения высказывались неоднозначные [Треугольник, но угла трИ?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/26277/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%98)

Comment: Спосиба. Агромнае.

Answer (score 2):

Трезубец — жезл с тр**е**мя зубцами. С **тремя**, а не <del>тримя</del>.

Трезубец — это копье, наконечник которого состоит из тр**е**х зубьев.

Государственный символ Украины называется **тризубом**, а не трезубцем.

[https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Герб_України](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B1_%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D0%B8)

Слово "трезубец" происходит от французского слова trident (тр**е**хзубый), которое, в свою очередь, происходит от латинского слова Tridens или tridentis: tri "три" и dentes "зубы". Вариант на санскрите Trishula является производным от tri "три" + sula "шип". Греческий эквивалент τρίαινα (tríaina), от прото-греческого trianja ("тройной").